# maven surefire: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye

Tags: maven

Hoy tratando de revivir un proyecto de maven que no tocaba en un tiempo me encontre con el siguiente error

Salida del log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ inventarios-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.757 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-09T23:14:15-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project inventarios-service: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\Inventarios\inventarios-service\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\\Users\\user\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.4\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\Inventarios\\inventarios-service\\target\\jacoco.exec --illegal-access=permit -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4997825414328274641\surefirebooter3832063640428513508.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4997825414328274641 2022-08-09T23-14-15_478-jvmRun1 surefire787675269873607625tmp surefire_06444923720016961325tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\\Users\\user\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.4\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\Inventarios\\inventarios-service\\target\\jacoco.exec --illegal-access=permit -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4997825414328274641\surefirebooter3832063640428513508.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4997825414328274641 2022-08-09T23-14-15_478-jvmRun1 surefire787675269873607625tmp surefire_06444923720016961325tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

A que se debera?

### datos de la computadora:

JDK: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_333

SO: Windows 10 de 64 bits.

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
        <artifactId>inventarios</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>inventarios-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>inventarios-service</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--spring data-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
            <artifactId>inventarios-entities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--integration tests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--unit tests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- compilation config-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- code coverage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.13.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${argLine} --illegal-access=permit</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

La linea que me daba problemas era

```
<argLine>${argLine} --illegal-access=permit</argLine>
```

Tras comentarla ya funciono perfectamente.

Asumo que esto sucede debido a que tanto en [appveyor](/questions/tagged/appveyor) como en [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) tengo configurado java por defecto y por cuestiones de licencia usan un Open JDK.